# Закрыть сессию в spring security приложении

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-session

У меня есть Spring-boot-приложение с подключенной системой авторизации пользователей (spring-security).
Есть обычные пользователи и пользователи-админы.
Приложение хранит текущие сессии в БД:

```
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
```

Мне необходимо:

1. Получить список текущих пользовательских сессий
2. Досрочно прекратить сессии всех пользователей кроме определённого.

Дело в том, что все примеры в интернете описывают работу либо со своей сессией (установка доп. атрибутов) либо тот случай, когда сессии хранятся в **памяти приложения** (класс org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl) а не в БД.

У меня же приложение может запускаться в кластере и сессии, повторюсь, хранятся в БД.
Вариант с перехватом события создания сессии (интерфейс AuthenticationSuccessHandler) и хранением списка отдельно тоже мне не подходит, так как приложение может рестартовать с активными сессиями в БД.

Сейчас я решаю 2-й пункт "в лоб", вызываю native sql query:

```
UPDATE public.spring_session SET max_inactive_interval = 1 WHERE principal_name != 'admin' OR principal_name IS NULL
```

Но, быть может, есть какой-то более элегантный способ?

Comment: Так закрыть сессию нельзя. Приведите самодостаточный пример.

Comment: Именно так, устанавливая поле max_inactive_interval в 1, я и"закрываю" сессию (следующий же запрос в рамках этой сессии возвращает 401 Unauthorized).

Answer (score 1):

Чувак, я бился с этим вопросом больше недели.
Натыкался и на твой вопрос, который почти два года стоял без ответа.

Я решил эту фигню

1. инжектим это

   private final FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<? extends Session> sessions;
2. делаем что-то вроде этого:

   ```
    public void deleteAllUserSessions(Users user) {
    //посик активных сессий пользователя и их удаление
    Collection<? extends Session> usersSessions = this.sessions
            .findByPrincipalName(user.getUsername()).values();
    for (Session userSession : usersSessions) {
        sessions.deleteById(userSession.getId());
    }
   ```

   }